# ffmpeg screen recording in background

Tags: video, ffmpeg, azure-devops

I would like to record my screen with ffmpeg during some automation work as a step in Azure devOps.
I can use some simple command like:

```
.\ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 10 -i desktop vid.avi
```

and it is working but for ADO this is one step in whole job so until it is not finished it will simply not go next step. I need this recording for whole job.
Right now when I run this command then command line is 'frozen' it is showing progress of recording. For ADO it means that this step is not finished. 
I would like to know if it's possible to run ffmpeg with some additional options so job still running but in the backgroud.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: to have video recording from automation job

Answer (score 0):

- pipelines are the overall definition of your ci cd process, they can contain multiple stages.
- stages are phases of your pipeline, like build, test, deploy... They can contain multiple jobs.
- jobs are collections of tasks/steps needed to implement your process. They contain one or more task/step.
- tasks or steps are the actual actions being executed like "execute this command" "build that dotnet project"...

Between each task or step that belong to the same job, you will keep the same environment and each task will "benefit" the outcome (files changed, environment variables...) From the previous ones.

I am afraid this is related your command. Suggest you use a self-host build agent and remote to your agent during build. Check the progress of your server for future troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Place the “&” ampersand, no quotes, at the end of the command you posted.   Then issue a command after the tests run to close this background task command.
Example:  mycommand.sh -withparameters &